# Can I see the specs of the memory card used within the metadata of an image?

Tags: metadata

I want to see the specs of the particular memory card (or serial number) I used on a particular image. Is this possible?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? What is do you want this information for?

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not part of the standard for EXIF, which means there's no standard way to store it in image files.

Comment: "Second, there's no standard for communicating this from the card to the camera." I think there is - [the CID register contains the serial number](https://www.cameramemoryspeed.com/sd-memory-card-faq/reading-sd-card-cid-serial-psn-internal-numbers/) so there's no reason the camera couldn't read that.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Is it possible that cheap knock-offs of brand name flash memory cards would all have the same serial number? Many reverse engineered third party lenses use this strategy to get cameras to recognize/work with them.

Comment: @MichaelClark Anything is possible - but my impression is that the knock-off merchants are wise to this specific trick. No proof though and getting off topic for photo SE.

Answer (score 0):

No, It's not possible. Because in the current design image doesn't includes the memory card information like seriel numbers. Because it'll not effect to image quality.

For more details about EXIF, please refer below link:-

https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/exif-photo-data-find-understand/